# How to delete custom metadata type record using apex

Tags: apex, metadata-api, custom-metadata

By using **CustomMetadata** class we can update or create custom metadata type records as below,

```
Metadata.CustomMetadata customMetadata =  new Metadata.CustomMetadata();
customMetadata.fullName = 'ISVNamespace__MetadataTypeName.MetadataRecordName';

Metadata.CustomMetadataValue customField = new Metadata.CustomMetadataValue();
customField.field = 'customField__c';
customField.value = 'New value';
customMetadata.values.add(customField);

Metadata.DeployContainer mdContainer = new Metadata.DeployContainer();
mdContainer.addMetadata(customMetadata);
...
Id jobId = Metadata.Operations.enqueueDeployment(mdContainer, callback);
```

But, How can we delete custom metadata record?

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custommetadatatypes_accessing.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null

Answer (score 3):

As Salesforce documentation says, this is not currently possible. You can just Read, Create and Update records.

> Apex code can create, read, and update (but not delete) custom metadata records, as long as the metadata is subscriber-controlled and visible from within the code's namespace.